# Ignore set of branches branches like origin/private_*

Tags: git

When I do `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all` I would like to see a graph for all the branches but private branches of other developers.

Can I tell `git log` to ignore branches matching a pattern, like `git log --all --ignore-branches="origin/private_*"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `--not` option. So this command should work.

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --not --remotes="origin/private_*"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `git log` command uses `git rev-list` to get commits to show, so all the things you can supply to `git rev-list` are available.

Unfortunately, there is no "all branches except ..." built in.  There *is* an option spelled `--remotes=`, which accepts shell-glob-style patterns, so you can look at, e.g., `--remotes="origin/[b-d]*"` to see `origin/brine`, `origin/bubbly`, and `origin/derp` while excluding `origin/argyle` and `origin/egret`.  But making that include everything except `origin/private_*` is again difficult.

If you are willing to invoke pipelines, `git for-each-ref` piped through `grep -v` is the obvious approach.  You can get `git for-each-ref` to produce all local and/or remote branch names, use `grep -v` to discard the unwanted ones, and supply the result as arguments to `git log`.